# Was it not possible to see Illumi's needle with gyo?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Hisoka uses In to conceal his bungee gum which is visible with gyo, so I figured Illumi must have also masked his needle with In. I think anyone could see with gyo that Killua has a different aura on him, even a little. Because that is certainly a nen needle.

So is Killua's luck just so bad that nobody ever noticed it and said something?

Answer (score 2):

well first of all killua didn't know how to use nen so of course he couldn't see what illumi was doing
And second of all I dont think anyone suspected anything while Illumi was putting a needle in killua's head

Comment: Yeah, but i was thinking how during the whole show, absolutely no one noticed it. Not even Wing and Biscuit, who used gyo in front of Killua.

Comment: Yes wing and biscuit used gyo in front of Killua but that was after illumi put the needle in Killua in other words it was after Killua learned how to use gyo